# Difficulty Exporting a list of computers To CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find all computers that have a certain folder on the C Drive.
I'm using a txt file of all computers I'm searching.
If the folder exists on the c drive, I want to export it to a CSV document.  If the folder doesn't exist, I don't need to do anything with it.

I also added a test-connection to skip any computers that are currently offline.

Currently, when I step through the code, it seems to hit each line correctly, and it creates the export csv document, however it is blank, without any columns or data.

I am afraid I might be coming at this problem at the wrong angle, since I am new.

Thank you.

```
$A = @(Get-Content 'c:\users\\me\computerlist.txt')
Foreach ($i in $A) {

    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $i -Quiet -Count 1) {
      Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression= 
      {$_}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Program 
      Files (x86)\Test"}} | Export-Csv \\me\C$\Users\me\Exported.csv
    }
    Else {Write-Host $i' not reachable'}
}
```

Like I said, debugging it - steps through seemingly correctly and created the export file, but nothing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Select-Object` call is receiving no input from the pipeline, so it sends nothing to the target file specified with `Export-Csv`.

(The target file is still created, empty, during pipeline *initialization*, even though no objects end up flowing through the pipeline.)

Use a single pipeline as follows; the automatic `$_` variable, which represents the input object at hand, refers to the computer name at hand throughout:

```
Get-Content 'c:\users\me\computerlist.txt' | 
  Where-Object { 
    $reachable = Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1
    if (-not $reachable) { Write-Host "$_ not reachable" }
    $reachable 
  } | Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},
                    @{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ (Test-Path "\\$_\c$\Program Files (x86)\Test")}} |
        Export-Csv \\me\C$\Users\me\Exported.csv
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @TheCheese444.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ForEach` isn't the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, but is instead the looping construct. You are thus not in a pipeline prior to the `Export-CSV`. Instead of using `$_` in the two expressions, use `$i`, which is the variable that you established at the top of the `ForEach(...)` loop:

```
$A = @(Get-Content 'c:\users\\me\computerlist.txt')
Foreach ($i in (Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\Me\ComputerList.txt")) {

    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $i -Quiet -Count 1) {
      Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$i}},@{Name='FolderExist';Expression={ (Test-Path "\\$i\c$\Program Files (x86)\Test")}} | Export-Csv \\me\C$\Users\me\Exported.csv
    }  #Note use of $i instead of $_ in above line
    Else {Write-Host $i' not reachable'}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that quick reply, looks like I missed a few ideas.  However after updating the script, still getting the same issue - an empty csv file.  It's being created but it's empty.  Again after using the debug tool in PowerShell_ise, everything seems right.  I'll continue to troubleshoot.  Thanks!